# Latest simplepie + codeigniter integration not working

Tags: codeigniter, simplepie

I have the latest simplepie (1.2.1 I believe) and CodeIgniter 2.1.0.

I converted simplepie.inc into simplepie.php and put it in the library folder. And followed instructions on http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

However, when I try to load it by

```
function test_simplepie()
{
  $this->load->library('simplepie');
  echo 'done';
}
```

I get a

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

error and nothing is displayed.

What would be the best way to moving forward with Simplepie + CI?

Comment: if you don't load the library, does it work? if yes then post the whole library code

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really supplied enough information for an answer here.

An empty response probably means a fatal error, so check your server error log. Also, the CI docs note that filenames need to be capitalised, so make sure it's called `SimplePie.php`, not `simplepie.php`